# Delete using mutiple session in oracle

Tags: oracle, session

I need to Archive one day worth data (7 million records) from multiple tables. I used for all bulk collect it took 30 mins to complete for single table. I want to know the significance of running the `delete` statement in multiple sessions based on the Primary key.

Suppose I have table `employee` with `emp_id` as primary key. If I ran the 
10 sessions in parallel and loop through 3 million records, would it improve the performance?

```
session 1
delete from employee where emp_id > 0 and emp_id< 10000;
session 2
delete from employee where emp_id => 10001 and emp_id< 20000;
session 3
delete from employee where emp_id => 20001 and emp_id< 30000;
session 4
delete from employee where emp_id => 30001 and emp_id< 40000;
session 5
delete from employee where emp_id => 40001 and emp_id< 50000;
session 6
delete from employee where emp_id => 50001 and emp_id< 60000;
session 7
delete from employee where emp_id => 60001 and emp_id< 70000;
session 8
delete from employee where emp_id => 70001 and emp_id< 80000;
session 9
delete from employee where emp_id => 80001 and emp_id< 90000;
session 10
delete from employee where emp_id => 90001 and emp_id< 100000;
```

TIA

Comment: It may, you can use dbms_parallel_execute package to do this but you have to test it out in your environment.

Comment: Are you using Enterprise Edition?  If so you may be able to use regular parallel SQL, that is `alter session enable parallel dml;`, `delete /*+ parallel(10) */ from employee where emp_id between 0 and 100000;`.

Comment: Hi Jon,I tried using the parallel hint but the optimizer is using the index scan and the parallel operation is ignored

Comment: @user2899615 How exactly did you use the parallel hint?  If you used an object-level hint, like `/*+ parallel(employee, 10) */`  then it may only apply to the table.  But a statement-level hint, `/*+ parallel(10) */` should force parallelism using any access methods.  And if that doesn't work, then `/*+ parallel(10) full(employee) */` should do it.

Comment: Hi Jon, The table to delete is 3 million and hence i would like to loop through 10k records .if i run the parallel hint with the forcing the employee table to do full table scan ,then each loop will do full table scan which is over head .if i run parallel hint does it not blow the undo